# Текст в файле встает не с первой строчки. PHP

Tags: php

Всем привет, не особо понимаю почему происходит такая проблема, но при генерации файла запись начинается не с первой строчки из-за чего вытекают проблемы

Код супер тривиальный (Скорее всего некоторые хедеры лишние, но работает - не трогай):

```
<?php

static function action_get_gpx_addresses(){
        $gpx_text_start ='<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\' standalone=\'yes\' ?>
          <metadata>
            <name>tmp</name>
            <author>
              <name>tmp</name>
              <link href="https://k-telecom.org/" />
            </author>
            <link href="https://k-telecom.org/" />
          </metadata>
          ';

        $gpx_test_end = '</gpx>';

        $gpx_content = '';
        $addresses = json_decode(Route::$query{'addresses'});
        foreach($addresses as $address){
            $gpx_content .= '<wpt lat="'.$address->{'lat'}.'" lon="'.$address->{'lng'}.'"><name>'.$address->{'address'}.'</name></wpt>'.PHP_EOL;
        }
        $output = $gpx_text_start.''.$gpx_content.''.$gpx_test_end;  
        $file_name = 'points_'.date("m.d.y").'.gpx';
        ob_clean();
        header ("Content-Type:text/xml");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$file_name);
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');  
        header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
        header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
        header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
        header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0
        header ('Location : index.php');
        echo $output;
        exit();
    }
 ?>
```

Проблема только в пустой первой строке, если ее убрать, то проблем никаких нет. Есть предположения как лечить?
[image: Скриншот]
[image: Окно скачивания]

Comment: А тебе не кажется хорошей идеей написать, *какие именно* вытекают у тебя проблемы?

Comment: @Ипатьев файл формата .gpx не парсится для отображения на Google Maps. Вот сообщение о самой ошибке "Ошибка синтаксического анализа XML: объявление XML или текста не в начале сущности". Приложил скриншот, VS Code даже не подсвечивает

Comment: Ну, учитывая что Google Maps по идее должны понимать BOM, остается только одна версия - что у тебя код который выполняется ранее, где-то выдает пустую строку

Comment: @Ипатьев в том то и проблема, что это весь код, который есть

Comment: разумеется это не весь. если ты поместишь "весь этот код" в РНР файл и попробуешь к нему обратиться через браузер, то он тупо выведется как есть, вместо твоего XML

Comment: `<?php`  небось написано не в начале файле или еще чего нить в этом роде

Comment: @teran скорее всего ?> закрытый тег где то в файлах до. Но на самом деле автору посоветовал бы использовать что то вроде simpleXML для генерации xml'ки

Comment: @Ипатьев поэтому файл передается на скачивание в формате .gpx? Благодарю за уделенное время, но в суть вопроса Вы явно не хотите вникнуть. Мне даже не сложно загрузить скриншот с окном скачивания файла

Comment: я вник, но вот теперь после твоего комментария действительно не хочу

Comment: @Ипатьев Молодец, еще и минусик поставил, надеюсь Ваше Эго было восстановлено

Comment: вот никогда не понимал, при чем здесь эго-то? Ну то есть понятно причем, но *моё*-то каким боком?

Comment: @DanzoSama не тупите, вам написали что это не весь код. ибо пхп код начинается с `<?php`. В приведенном фрагменте текста не весь исполняемый пхп файл. был бы он именно таким, как указано просто бы скачался текстом. постаить die перед всем этим, все равно получите пустую строку в выводе.

Comment: @teran Правил код. Но проблему уже решил своими силами, я забыл про существование ob_clean(). Спасибо за уделенное время

Comment: Не поправил ты ничего. Теперь этот код, вызванный сам по себе,  будет выводить ошибку Class Route not found. Давай, продолжай рассказывать нам сказки что это весь прям перевесь код, какой есть, больше никакого нету. Как будто ты зерно в подвале прячешь, а мы типа красные комиссары пришли его забирать

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Решение было в добавлении `ob_clean()` перед объявлением заголовков `header`

Comment: Это называется не решение, а "костыль"

Comment: `ob_clean` лишь подтверждает, то пустая строка выводится раньше.